# Remove all disabled attribute with button click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, forms, attributes

I have a form with about 30 fields. Some are input number fields, some are input text fields, and others are textareas, some even use a currency component fields. Here are some examples of the fields:

```
<NumberFormat
    value={this.state.tax}
    displayType={'input'}
    isNumericString={true}
    thousandSeparator={true}
    decimalScale={2}
    prefix={'$'}
    className="phone validate"
    name="Sales Tax"
    disabled                                        
/>  

<div className={`${styles.singleField} ${styles.smallField}`}>
    <label>
        Options
    </label>
    <select name="OptionList" value={this.state.OptionList} className="phone validate" disabled> 
        <option value="One">One</option>
        <option value="Two">Two</option>
        <option value="Three">Three</option>                        
    </select>
</div>

<div className={`${styles.singleField} ${styles.largeField}`}>
    <label>
        Product
    </label>
    <input
        value={this.state.product}
        type="text"
        className="phone validate"
        name="Detailed Description"
        maxLength={45}
        disabled
    />
</div>
```

I want to create a button that says `edit form` that will then remove all disabled tag from the form to allow the user to edit the form. Here is what I have. All of the fields have the `className` `validation` I'm hoping I can grab them by that.

```
<button onClick={this.editForm.bind(this)} className={styles.btn}>Edit Form</button>

    async editForm(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log('Trigger to edit form');
        
        //Code here to remove disabled attirubutes 
    }
```

Comment: I would suggest you control it via state having variable disabled: true, and binded to all the elements of form , when you click the button , update the state to false. This should work fine for you !

Comment: @Harmandeep Singh Kalsi can you explain a little more? So like have a `isDisabled={false}` like that or?

Comment: Declare a state variable : this.state = {disabled: true} , then bind to the form elements like <input  disabled={this.state.disabled}/> . On click , bind the handler : <button type="button" onClick={this.clickHandler.bind(this)} /> and in the method , you can update the state : clickHandler(){this.setState({disabled: false})}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use React's state management for this. I'm not sure if this is inside of a class component or a functional component but here's how you can achieve what you're looking for.

Also the React documentation covers [State and Lifecycles](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) I would recommend reading through these.

Class Component [CodePen](https://codepen.io/kjscott27/pen/ExPpGZb):

```
class YourComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      inputsDisabled: true
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      ...yourcodehere
      <button onClick={() => this.setState({ inputsDisabled: false })}>Click Me</button>
      <input disabled={this.state.inputsDisabled} />
    )
  }
}
```

Functional Component:

```
const YourComponent = () => {
  const [inputsDisabled, setInputsDisabled] = React.useState(false)
    return (
      ...yourcodehere
      <button onClick={() => this.setState({ inputsDisabled: false })}>Click Me</button>
      <input disabled={inputsDisabled} />
    )
  }
}
```